# How can I intelligently group rows of integers for a faceted search?

Tags: c#, math, statistics

I'm not even quite sure what terms I should be using for what I want, so any advice on what I'm even asking for would be very welcome.

Basically, my web site lists user-generated accommodations. Each has a rent price, which users will be able to query in our new faceted search box.

Users search by city, and within each city I'd like to present a *different* rent grouping. That is to say that in City #1, if we have listings ranging from $200 - $1000, I'd like to present checkboxes for:

- less than $300
- $301 - $500
- $501 - $700
- more than $700

However, if City #2 has values that range from $500 - $1500, I want the ranges above to change accordingly. So, if I say that I want 5 or 6 range options in each city, I think I have two options:

1. Take the min and max values and just split the difference. I don't like this idea because one listing with a rent of $10,000 will throw the whole scale off.
2. Intelligently calculate the ranges using means, medians etc.

Number 2 is what I need help with. I'm a web developer that gets logic, but was never strong on math and statistics at school. Can anyone point me towards a guide that'll help me figure this out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking for 4 groups, you need 3 splitpoints.  Take the median of your whole set to get the middle one, then the median of those above and below that to get your other two.

Comment: Perfect! This is a much better solution than using the mean, as it won't be sensitive to outliers. :)

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much. Working out three split points, then doing a little number rounding to make it look nicer ($200 is better than $203, in my case) and my price filter is working great.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to figure out the scale dynamically based upon the data set, why not have a static scale (or formula for determining scale) and then determine if there is data to support displaying the search options.

For example, if your scale is `[(0-300), (301, 600), (601-700), ...]` and your dataset contains [$250, $500, $550, $1000] then you would need to display `[(0-300), (301-600), (1001-1300)]`.

You could figure this out with LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

Split your data by quantity.

Something like this (pseudo-C code):
Let "set" be the data, "n" be the number of entries, and "s" be the number of splits.

```
int increment = ceil(n/s);
int start = 0;
int end = increment;
OrderSet(set); // So set[0] is min and set[n-1] is max
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
{
  while (set[end] == set[start] && end < n - 1)
    end++;
  AddGroup(start, end);

  if (end == n - 1)
    break;

  start = end;
  end = start + increment;
  if (end >= n)
    end = n - 1;
}
```